# Quartz jobs failing after MySQL db errors

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

On a working Grails 2.2.5 system, we're occasionally losing connection to the MySQL database, for reasons that are not relevant here. The majority of the system recovers perfectly well from the outage. But any Quartz jobs (using Quartz plugin 0.4.2) are typically failing to run again after such an outage. This is a typical message which appears in the log at the point the job should run:

```
2015-02-26 16:30:45,304 [quartzScheduler_Worker-9] ERROR core.ErrorLogger  - Unable to notify JobListener(s) of Job to be executed: (Job will NOT be executed!). trigger= GRAILS_JOBS.quickQuoteCleanupJob job= GRAILS_JOBS.com.aire.QuickQuoteCleanupJob
org.quartz.SchedulerException: JobListener 'sessionBinderListener' threw exception: Already value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@593a9498] for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@c8488d7] bound to thread [quartzScheduler_Worker-9] [See nested exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@593a9498] for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@c8488d7] bound to thread [quartzScheduler_Worker-9]]
        at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.notifyJobListenersToBeExecuted(QuartzScheduler.java:1868)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.notifyListenersBeginning(JobRunShell.java:338)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:176)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@593a9498] for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@c8488d7] bound to thread [quartzScheduler_Worker-9]
        at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.notifyJobListenersToBeExecuted(QuartzScheduler.java:1866)
        ... 3 more
```

What do I need to do to make things more robust, so that the Quartz jobs recover as well?

Answer (score 1):

By default, a Quartz job will get a session bound to it. Disable that session binding and let your service handle the transaction / session. That's what we do and when we get our DB connections back up, jobs still work.

To disable session binding in your job, add :

```
def sessionRequired = false
```

Comment: I'll give that a try, thanks. I think the problem may actually be do to with the Quartz mechanism itself and its interactions with the database, rather than specific database usage within the jobs, but I haven't been able to determine that yet. I've just upgraded to version 1.0.2 of the plugin in the hope that that will handle things a bit better. One irritating problem I have at the moment is that whenever I do take down the MySQL database, I get thousands of lines of errors being written to the log in seconds.